# How to remove dropped event in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar

My JS code like:

```
 drop: function (event, delta, ev, resourceId, res) {
            var title = $(this).html();
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>Administrative_affairs/add_events',
                data: {
                 start: event.format(),
                 end: event.format(),
                 vacation_id: $(this).attr('id-val')
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "POST",
                success: function(eventId) {
                    var myEvent = {
                      title: title,
                      id: eventId,
                      start: event.format(),
                      end: event.format()
                    };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',myEvent);
 },
```

it add an event to my calendar but twice one from `rendering` and the second from my dropping. I want to keep the one I render, so how to remove the other one that I drop!!

Comment: don't remove it, or re-render it, just _update_ it.